# screen output **write(A,'+',B,'=',C)** for android

Tags: android

1) is there any easy way for screen output like in Pascal: write(A,'+',B,'=',C) ?

I tried :

```
void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.new_layout);
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    int A,B,C;
    A=4;
    B=8;
    C=A+B;
    String text = getString(A,"+",B,"=",C);

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);               
    tv.setText(text);
    //Toast.makeText(this,text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
```

but ít doesn't work. 
Every time I will get "...apliccation has stopped"

the best would be something like :
        tv.setText(A,"+",B,"=",C) //without stringing integers;

thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate the string and use `setText` afterwards:

```
tv.setText(A + "+" B + "=" + C);
```

For longer text, use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Perfect, it hepls. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong `getString(A,"+",B,"=",C)`

you want

`String text = A + "+" + B + "=" + C;`

---

`getString` is used for retrieving package string resources

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString%28int%29)

Comment: thank you for the answer. Hopefully I will use it in the future - beginner.